# Every derived table has its own alias

Tags: mysql

i have the following query:

```
select userid, name, checktime, campaign,

CASE WHEN Hoursworked - 9 > 0 THEN Hoursworked - 9 ELSE 0 END Overtime
from
(

    select  
    a.userid,a.name,a.campaign,

    date(a.CHECKTIME),
    timediff(max(b.CHECKTIME), min(a.CHECKTIME)) as Hoursworked
    from CHECKINOUT a

    join CHECKINOUT b

    on date(a.CHECKTIME) = date(b.CHECKTIME) and a.userid = b.userid
    where
    a.CHECKTYPE = 'I'

    AND b.CHECKTYPE = 'O'

    group by date(a.CHECKTIME), userid
)
```

**And it's giving this error**

## 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

can you help me what wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [add a name for the subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) that you have used.

> Subqueries are legal in a SELECT statement's FROM clause. The actual
>   syntax is:
>
> `SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...`
>
> The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM
>   clause must have a name. Any columns in the subquery select list must
>   have unique names.

So give your subquery an alias by:

```
select userid, name, checktime, campaign,

CASE WHEN Hoursworked - 9 > 0 THEN Hoursworked - 9 ELSE 0 END Overtime
from
(

    select  
    a.userid,a.name,a.campaign,

    date(a.CHECKTIME),
    timediff(max(b.CHECKTIME), min(a.CHECKTIME)) as Hoursworked
    from ...
) AS T  --here is the alias
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the table alias for the temp subtable

in this case see the added  `as t` at the bottom

```
select userid, name, checktime, campaign,

CASE WHEN Hoursworked - 9 > 0 THEN Hoursworked - 9 ELSE 0 END Overtime
from
(

    select  
    a.userid,a.name,a.campaign,

    date(a.CHECKTIME),
    timediff(max(b.CHECKTIME), min(a.CHECKTIME)) as Hoursworked
    from CHECKINOUT a

    join CHECKINOUT b

    on date(a.CHECKTIME) = date(b.CHECKTIME) and a.userid = b.userid
    where
    a.CHECKTYPE = 'I'

    AND b.CHECKTYPE = 'O'

    group by date(a.CHECKTIME), userid
) as t
```